# Receiving "ReferenceError: mongoose not defined", despite being defined in app.js and installed through npm

Tags: node.js, mongoose, referenceerror

I'm building a pretty straightforward tool that will POST the contents of a form to the MongoDB, and will later build a GET request to pull it back out. It started off as following a tutorial and has spun off when I started building a more robust front-end, but I have not been able to get this aspect of the back-end functional.

Below is my code, and you can clearly see mongoose is defined as a variable..

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

var port = 3000;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
global.Promise = mongoose.Promise
console.log(console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/formnote");

var nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 srNumber: String,
 summary: String,
 notePad: String,
});


var Notes = mongoose.model("Notes", nameSchema);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
     res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/addnote", (req, res) => {
    var myData = new Notes(req.body);
    myData.save()
        .then(item => {
            res.send("Notes saved to database");
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send("Unable to save to database");
        });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: can u add the full error stack trace

Comment: I was unable to get a trace using console.trace(); any advice for that? I'm still fairly new with Javascript development.

Answer (score 0):

just a shot in the dark. But there are problems when using mongoose global promise 
in new mongoose version that implementation you have used to connect to your database is obsolete and replaced with this implemenatation

so instead of these lines to connect to the database,

```
global.Promise = mongoose.Promise
console.log(console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/formnote");
```

use this and try

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/formnote',{useNewUrlParser:true})
    .then(function(){
        console.log('mongoDB connected');
    })
    .catch(function(){
        console.log('Error :');
    })
```

Comment: I had read on one post about that deprecation and had tried removing the promise, and am currently looking into using bluebird as well. I tried that snippet of code into it as well though and it did not resolve. I'm pretty sure its not even getting to the connect phase though due to the ReferenceError. I believe it's a problem with the variable itself.

Answer (score 0):

I restructured my code some to allow for more organization when configuring my API itself, and in the process also changed from var to const on my requirements. This seems to have resolved this issue